# describing the motion of a particle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

> Find the velocity, speed, and acceleration, and describe the motion of a particle whose position at time t is:
>
> $r = 3\cos(\omega t)i+4\cos(\omega t)j + 5\sin(\omega t)k$

They then note in regards to the motion:

> Observe $|r| = 5$. Therefore, the path of the particle lies on the sphere with equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 25$. Since $x=3\cos(\omega t)$ and $y = 4\cos(\omega t)$, the path also lies on the vertical plane $4x = 3y$.

I don't understand the reasoning behind the sphere. I rely much on the principles used in order to trace a graph for 3-dimensional, i.e the general equations for different parabloids and cylinders in 3d.

So I'm not sure how to trace with coordinates $ x=3\cos(\omega t)$,$ y = 4\cos(\omega t)$ and $ z = 5\sin(\omega t)$.

How does the magnitude of $r$ determine that the particle lies on sphere? I cannot reconcile this with previous literature.

Comment: How do you define a sphere?

Comment: As they define it on Wikipedia "A sphere is a perfectly round geometrical object in three-dimensional space that is the surface of a completely round ball"

Why?

Comment: A sphere is the set of all points in space that are equidistant from a given point. Every point on that curve is a distance of $5$ away from the origin.

Comment: My question might've been unclear. I don't see how they get $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =25$ from $r = 3cos(\theta t)i + 4cos(\theta t)j + 5sin(\theta t)k$ shouldn't the graph instead be something more elliptical?

Comment: $x^2+y^2+z^2=9\cos^2(\theta t)+16\cos^2(\theta t)+25\sin^2(\theta t)=25\cos^2(\theta t)+25\sin^2(\theta t)=25$

Comment: @JohnDouma Can't believe that I did not see that. I guess i'm still getting used to how the graphs work in 3d. Thank you!